# Link from image not ending on image

Tags: html, css

I have been making a website for a friend of mine http://fourstago.tk/default.html and for some reason the links on the sidebar dont end on the image and make the whole page a link. ive made a small image that does nothing but its still an annoying issue.

Comment: Are you sure you want the following anchor <a> tag to wrap the content inside it or if this tag is necessary?
*********************************************************************************************************************************
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">
</a>

Comment: This doesn't make a great deal of sense... considor revising the question? Also, an example of your code would have been appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the anchor tag towards the bottom of the page. That is why it happens. Keep the anchor tag just above the img tag and close the anchor tag just after end of img tag.

eg:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</a>
```